# How to relate outgoing email to Salesforce Lead and auto-creating Email Activity on Lead Record when sent?

Tags: lightning, email, leads, salesforce-for-outlook, lightning-outlook

I have enabled `Lightning for Outlook` and `Enhanced Email with Lightning for Outlook`. Also I have installed `Lightning for Outlook` plugin in my outlook but I don't see any option to relate email to lead. I don't know if it is possible or not.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Leads are not supported out of the box - it does not search automatically for leads.

But, you can search for the lead by it's name:

[image]

Then select it when the search find it:

[image]

Then click `Log` to relate this lead to the email:

[image]

Also - for creating new leads, vote on this idea:

[Lightning for Outlook - Add New Lead and Support for Multiple Record Types](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E6CcQAK)